# Как правильно воспользоваться Enum типом (перечисления)?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Есть валидный тип перечисления, доставшийся в наследство от генератора кода:

```
create or replace type e_MyEnum as object (
        dummy number(1),
        static function YES return varchar2 deterministic,
        static function NO return varchar2 deterministic
)
/
create or replace type body e_MyEnum as
        static function YES return varchar2 deterministic as begin return 'YES'; end;
        static function NO return varchar2 deterministic as begin return 'NO'; end;
end;
/
```

Как корректно пользоваться таким типом?

При попытке задать значение переменной в любом виде, получаю ошибки:

```
declare
  a e_MyEnum;
begin
  a := e_MyEnum.YES;
end;
/
PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type

declare
  a e_MyEnum;
begin
  a := 1;
end;
/
PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type

declare
  a e_MyEnum;
begin
  a.dummy := 1;
end;
/
ORA-06530: Reference to uninitialized composite
```

Ошибки: "Выражение не правильного типа" - это понятно. Но в последнем случае: "ссылка на не инициализированный составной тип", но тип же уже создан в БД и его можно посмотреть.

Как правильно присвоить, считать и сравнить переменную типа перечисление?

Comment: Не ассоциация, это удалённый вопрос одного из активных участников ruSO.

Answer (score 4):

У этого пользовательского типа нет атрибутов (кроме `dummy`=пустышка), а значит нет данных которые надо хранить.

Создавать сущность этого типа, например `a e_MyEnum`, нет никакого смысла. Присвоить какое-либо значение можно только инициализированной сущности типа.
Поэтому, объявление переменной этого типа и присвоение ей значений, нецелесообразно.

Статические функции этого типа можно использовать в PL/SQL контексте так:

```
declare
    val varchar2 (3);
begin
    val := e_MyEnum.YES;
    if val = e_MyEnum.YES then null; end if;
end;
/

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Или в SQL контексте так:

```
select * from (
    select e_MyEnum.NO() val from dual
) where val = e_MyEnum.NO() 
/

VAL
---
NO
```

Answer (score 2):

Есть более простой и понятный способ, эмулирующий тип перечисления:

```
create or replace package const as
    yes constant char (3) := 'YES';
    no  constant char (2) := 'NO';
end;
/
```

Вот простейший пример его использования:

```
var rc refcursor
declare 
    answ constant varchar (8) := const.no;
begin 
    open :rc for select const.yes yes, answ answ 
        from dual where const.no = answ;
end;
/

YES                              ANSW                            
-------------------------------- --------------------------------
YES                              NO
```